# ¿Cuál puede ser en este caso, la causa de este error "TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable"?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

Con el fin de acceder al número total de parámetros globales de *matplotlib*, ejecuto la sentencia siguiente:

```
# load package
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator,FormatStrFormatter,MaxNLocator
%matplotlib inline

# Número globals de variables
a = list(mpl.rcParams.keys) 
len(a)
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-5-f13500a53881> in <module>
>       1 # Número globals de variables
> ----> 2 a = list(mpl.rcParams.keys)
>       3 len(a)
>
> TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable
> ```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?

Agradeceré ayuda para fijar este error.

Comment: No has invocado al metodo keys. Es decir, debe ser `mpl.rcParams.keys()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El tipo de objeto como bien se indica es un método: Un método es una función que «pertenece a» un objeto.**

Por ejemplo: Si tienes un objeto llamado perro.ladrar() el método es ladrar, lo cual no puede ser iterable porque es un método de perro.
Pero si le agregas el método .keys() te lo arroja en una colección, y luego le aplicas el metodo list() para que lo tengas en una lista.

Te dejo el código:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator,FormatStrFormatter,MaxNLocator
%matplotlib inline

# Número globals de variables
a = list(mpl.rcParams.keys())
a
```